# Memory size issue regarding PayPal iOS SDk

Tags: ios, xcode, paypal

I created one demo project for PayPal SDK integration-iOS . I did CocoaPods for this and automatically my **Xcode app size is: 350MB**

But one of my Android developer did PayPal integration in Android. But the size of application is: **675KB**

**iOS- PayPal SDK size: 350MB**

**Android-PayPal SDK size: 675KB**

I want to know the clarification about size issue. If any one knows please help me out regarding this issue